# How to replace specific item in a collection of items in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a bit of a problem in Laravel. I'm using a collection where I add in new users which have been registered to a particular activity. These are formatted in the following way

```
{
 [
  "ID" => "1",
  "Email" => "test@example.com",
  "Registrations" => [
    "Sports" => [
      [
       "id" => "457",
       "title" => "Football"
      ], 
      [
       "id" => "459",
       "title" => "Rugby"
      ]
    ]
  ]
 ],
 [
  "ID" => "2",
  "Email" => "test2@example.com",
  "Registrations" => [
    "Sports" => [
      [
       "id" => "457",
       "title" => "Football"
      ], 
      [
       "id" => "458",
       "title" => "Badminton"
      ]
    ]
  ]
 ]
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when attempting to add a new Sports id I'm not sure how to go about it. The way I originally thought about doing it is checking if that particular email has already been registered and then replacing the data within the collection. However I encountered a problem with each time there was an existing entry the whole data structure would get replaced. Any helpful advice? Below is a reference to what I already have

```
        return $user_courses->where('ContactID' , $user['Registration']['Link']['Contact']['ContactID'])
        ->map(function($key) use ($user, $sportService){
            $course_id = $sportService->validateSport($user['Registration']['Link']['Activity']['ContentUri']);
            if($course_id){
                $key['Registrations']['Sports'][] = [
                    'id' => $course_id,
                    'title' => $user['Registration']['Link']['Activity']['Title']
                ];
                return $key;
            }
            return $key;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you can filter that object that you want to replace from the collection and then push the new object to it.

checkout this [link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/laravel+replace+item+in+collection+laravel)